# PHPMailer - Hangs

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer, freeze

I am trying to send an email via PHPMailer. I have unzipped the PHPMailer file to the server and have this code. I have the extra 'require' as it has been suggested in other posts regarding hanging when sending.

It is reading the code as if I miss out the 'body' I get an error message saying so.

I have tried multiple examples of different code as below and all hang. I have added and altered and now given up! I have a simple button that calls this code and the browser (tried multiple) just hangs. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'PHPMailer/class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                // Set mailer to use SMTP

$mail->Host = 'smtp.eastlink.ca';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers

$mail->Username = 'ns@eastlink.ca';                 // SMTP username

$mail->Password = '*******';                           // SMTP password

$mail->From = 'ns@eastlink.ca';

$mail->FromName = 'bob';

$mail->addAddress('dsmith@eastlink.ca', 'D');     // Add a recipient

$mail->addReplyTo('ns@eastlink.ca', 'Information');

$mail->isHTML(true);          // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';

$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {

    echo 'Message could not be sent.';

    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

} else {

    echo 'Message has been sent';

}
```

Comment: You don't need that extra require. Don't depend on SO for everything - there is a lot of bad advice around. Go [straight to the source](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), use the examples, read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to specifying a port

Try adding:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 25;
```

See: http://my.eastlink.ca/customersupport/internet/faqs/email.aspx

According to EastLink Doc, when connected with wireless device (not  shared):

Server Type: SMTP
Port: 465 or 587
Server Name: smtp.eastlink.ca
Use STARTTLS

So Try:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
// OR 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Comment: You don't have to: PHPMailer defaults to port 25.

Comment: Code still missing: 

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have added the lines as suggest and I get the message:  Extension missing: openssl
Mailer Error: Extension missing: openssl 
Looks like I have to edit the php.ini file. Thanks again